# Routing in Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am new to MVC 4 and Web API and I am currently working on a demo project, please tell me if you need any further clarification on the following question.

How do I implement various categories in a controller class if my routing looks as follows

`api/{controller}/public/{category}/{id}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using web api 2. enable attribute routing in web api config

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Attribute routing.
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Convention-based routing.
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

in the application start method

```
   protected void Application_Start()
{
    // Pass a delegate to the Configure method.
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
}
```

if your controler method expects category name and id as parameters and the method is a get method.

```
 public class YourController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("public/{category}/{id}")]
        [HttpGet]
        public Category GetCategoryInfo([FromUri]string category,[FromUri]int id ) { ... }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I am currently working in a .NET 4.0 environment, which does not support Web API 2.0. In that case what is the best solution ? Basically

Comment: am not sure, please try this https://www.nuget.org/packages/AttributeRouting.WebApi,  also refer http://www.strathweb.com/2012/05/attribute-based-routing-in-asp-net-web-api/

Comment: Thanks again for the clarification. This one is not compatible with log4net and hence throwing error when I run the application.

Comment: are you getting a build error? if so please can u tell me the error?

Comment: Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. Also PreApplicationStartCode.cs not found.

Comment: Try to find what is the dependency which log4net is missing , check whether it has any dependency with- AttributeRouting.Core (≥ 3.5.6)
AttributeRouting.Core.Web (≥ 3.5.6)
AttributeRouting.Core.Http (≥ 3.5.6)
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost (≥ 4.0.20710.0)
WebActivator (≥ 1.0.0.0)   any of these,  also add PreApplicationStartCode.cs to your project .

Comment: Most probably its clashing with AttributeRouting.Logging or AttributeRouting.Web.Logging and the older version of log4net resolves this issue. But now I have another issue, when I put [GET("Resources")] its not getting redirected to the concern url. Am I missing something ?

Comment: when you call http://yourApplication/YourControllerName/routAttributeName , (here your routeAttibuteName is "Resources"). What is the response you get? try in browser as well as fiddler or any other RestConsole .

Comment: 'http://localhost:61435/api/Dashboard/Resources its going to the main Get method which is equivalent to http://localhost:61435/api/Dashboard. While http://localhost:61435/api/Resources for this URL No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI error comes up. My method is in the Dashboard controller <code>  [GET("Resources")]
        //[AttributeRouting.Web.Mvc.Route("Resources")]
        public List<Notice> Test(int id)
        {
            return _dashboardService.GetNotices(50);
        }</code>

Comment: so do you mean to say  that   localhost:61435/api/Resources should be  able to call same resourse found at localhost:61435/api/Dashboard (infact you dont want the controller name in the url). if so you need to add a new value in the route table (in register routes method) like this routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Root",
    routeTemplate: "api/resources/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Dashboard", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);                                  please mark the answer if it is helpful